# how can I do SAX parsing method in android?

Tags: android, xml

I am implementing XML parsing in android.
Can anyone help me out by telling what I must do to implement a SAX parsing method in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can also give Android's own SAX parser a spin. I have tried using it and it works great.  This is based on the sample code from the IBM site also.

```
public class ParseXML {

private URL feedUrl;

public ParseXML(String urlSource){
    try {
        this.feedUrl = new URL(urlSource);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


protected InputStream getInputStream() {
    try {
        return feedUrl.openConnection().getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}


public YourDataContainer parse(){
    YourDataContainer container = new YourDataContainer();

    RootElement root = new RootElement("root");

    Element firstChild = root.getChild("element1");
    firstChild.getChild("entry1").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {

        public void end(String body) {
            container.setFirstEntry(body);
        }
    });
    firstChild.getChild("entry2").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {

        public void end(String body) {
            container.setSecondEntry(body);
        }
    });


    try {
        Xml.parse(this.getInputStream(), Xml.Encoding.ISO_8859_1, root.getContentHandler());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return container;
}
```

Where YourContainer has fields for the values you want to save and getters and setters.

This will parse something like this:

```
<root>
    <element1>
        <entry1>this is</entry1>
        <entry2>a test</entry2>
    </element1>
</root>
```

At the end of the run, YourContainer will have firstEntry="this is" and secondEntry="a test".

Answer (score 1):

I'll link you to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011985/retrieving-html-encoded-text-from-xml-using-saxparser/4033227#4033227). That should help you get started. For basics, just google Java SAX Parsing.